# Google Analytics Custom Parameter Name

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to track if page views come from navbar, header, footer, etc. The Google Analytics parameters are long and annoying. Does Google Analytics support custom `GET` parameter names?
For example the url:

```
example.com/login?utm_source=navbar&utm_medium=local-click&utm_campaign=referer
```

Could be

```
example.com/login?ref=nav
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by views?  Are you talking about clicking on a menu item in the navbar?  (Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.)

Comment: @DaImTo I want to shorten the UTM paramaters. Is it possible to have a custom name for them? I.e `?utm_campaign=ref&utm_source=navbar` could be shortened to `?ref=nav`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Campaign Data Import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-campaign). Simply upload a file which maps one value to many, for example ga:campaignCode to ga:medium,ga:source,ga:dimension1 and in your tracking code simply set the campaignId from your ref=nav.

```
// Create the tracker.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Set the campaign code/id directly.
ga('set', 'campaignId', '1234');

// Send the page view.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In fact there is a [good example of using url parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/plugins#example) to set values on tracker by using plugins along side of analytics.js.